# Pure JavaScript cut image from left, top, right, bottom

Tags: javascript

I am trying to cut image from left, top, right and bottom of a picture using pure JavaScript. It's working if provide just anyone potion like the left/top/right/bottom. When I provide left, top both it shows an unexpected result.

```
function resizeImage(url, options, callback) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageObj = new Image();

        var img = document.getElementById('originalImg')
        var w = img.clientWidth
        var h = img.clientHeight
        console.log(w, h);
        // set canvas dimensions
        var newWidth = w, newHeight = h


        if (options.hasOwnProperty('left')) {
            newWidth = w - options.left;
            newHeight = h
            console.log('Left: ', newWidth, newHeight)
            //update canvas size
            canvas.width = newWidth;
            canvas.height = newHeight;

            imageObj.src = url;
            imageObj.onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(imageObj, options.left, 0, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                callback(canvas.toDataURL());
            };

        }

        if (options.hasOwnProperty('top')) {
            newWidth = newWidth;
            newHeight = newHeight - options.top
            console.log('Top: ', newWidth, newHeight)
            //update canvas size
            canvas.width = newWidth;
            canvas.height = newHeight;

            imageObj.src = url;
            imageObj.onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, options.top, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                callback(canvas.toDataURL());
            };
        }
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        var cropImg = document.getElementById('cropImg')
        var btn = document.getElementById('btnCrop')
        var img = document.getElementById('originalImg')

        btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            //values in px
            var options = { left: 150, top: 50 }
            resizeImage(img.src, options, function (data) {
                cropImg.src = data
            })
        })
    }
```

When I provide only `var options = { left: 150 }` it's work fine and I am getting the output picture cropped 150px from left but it's not working for multiple value `var options = { left: 150, top: 50 }`
[image: Left crop work]
[image: Left, Top crop unexpected result]

I can not figure out where is my fault. Please help me to solve this logical bug. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like when you try to apply "left,top" only top is being applied... Possible for you to create a working demo? This will give myself and others something to work with which can help give you a solution much faster.

Comment: both are applied. In the 2nd image top is works but left is working from the right side of the image which is unexpected.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

On the case 'top' you overwrite the function set in the case 'left'. There you set the  second parameter (named sx in the definition) of the function call `context.drawImage(...)` to 0 wheras it was options.left in the case 'left'.

```
imageObj.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, options.top, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    callback(canvas.toDataURL());
};
```

You should extract this snippet from the cases 'top' and  'left' and have one general version of it after the `if`s, which fits all cases.